# Customize go-swagger generate spec

Tags: go, go-swagger

I am using go-swagger to generate spec with command `swagger generate spec`. Everything is working fine, however I want to mitigate possible mismatch between specs and actual implementation.

For example, the below model is having `required : true` in comment (for spec generation), as well as `value:"required"` for actual validation (e.g with [govalidator](http://github.com/asaskevich/govalidator))

```
    // Current model
    // swagger:parameters myAPI
    type Post struct {
        // the title
        // required : true
        Title   string `json:"Title" valid:"required"`

        // the message
        Message string `json:"Message"`
    }
```

Is there any way to customize go-swagger to parse `valid:"required"` and automatically add `required:true` in generated specs? I know that currently `swagger generate spec` is already checking `json:"Tittle"` to populate json field name `Title`. Any pointer will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked `go-swagger` source [code](https://github.com/go-swagger/go-swagger/blob/master/scan/parameters.go), and found out that in current implemented design, we can't do this. Basically, the scanning logic just checks the comment and JSON tag only.